What to do when Mail is stuck on "Loading..." a message in a conversation?
Sometimes Apple Mail gets stuck in this situation:

The messages load fine on iOS, iPadOS (both v17), and on iCloud.com.
On the Mac (M3 Max, Sonoma 14.5) some conversations get into this state.
Any idea how to get out of this?
I have already rebuilt the mailbox, restarted the system, and restarted Mail.
Thank you
